# Kendo Confirm overlapping with Kendo alert

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

My problem is when there is any update changes at the page its supposed to be kendo confirm will go out first then will kendo alert. How to manage it? But, based on my code the output is kendo confirm overlapping with kendo alert "successfully update".

**JavaScript alert**

```
   //AJAX call for button
    $("#primaryTextButton").kendoButton();
    var button = $("#primaryTextButton").data("kendoButton");
    button.bind("click", function(e) {

    var test = $("#dropdown").val()

    $.ajax({
        url: "../DesignationProgramTemplate/testing.php",
        type: "post",
            data: {'id':test,'progid':array},
                success: function (respond) {
                // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                 
                    //kendo.alert('Success'); // alert notification

                if(respond === "SUCCESS")
                {
                    kendo.alert("Successfully save data!");

                }else
                {   
                    var answer = kendo.confirm("Update the data?");  

                    if(answer)
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "del.php",
                        data: {'id':test,'progid':array},
                        success: function(){
                            kendo.alert("Successfully Update!");
                        }

                    });
                    }  
                }   
                },
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kendo.confirm](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/confirm) returns a [promise](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise).

As seen in their documentation:

```
kendo.confirm("Confirm text")
    .done(function(){
        console.log("User accepted");
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log("User rejected");
    });
```

In your code, `if(answer)` only checks if there is a promise. What you need to do is for the user to either resolve it or reject it.